# How can I zip 2 observables so I get one observables with two rows?

Tags: angular, zip, observable

I'm currently working on a project I inherited from my predecessor, where we take data from an outside source and want to visualize it.
The code I inherited provides two observables each with a value array (both of equal length). I want to zip these observables, so I get one observable, where instead of (index:value) like before, I get (value1:value2).

I tried the zip-function from rxjs, but that only put the two observables unchanged into another observable and I tried to map the content of the observables onto the new observable, but apparently observables cant be mapped.
It may be obvious, but Im very new to this entire rxjs thing.

Comment: can you explain a bit more `but apparently observables cant be mapped.`? i use `map()` operator all the time to map values and didn't have any problem with it.

Comment: Show the source code of what you've tried, and give an example of the inputs and outputs for the data you want.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the code that does not work?  See [ask] which suggests, *Help others reproduce the problem... Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you've got two observables, each firing exactly once. Both yield an array. You'd like to pair up these two arrays and convert them to a list of tuples (or a hashtable). Admittedly, that's a bit of guesswork here.

After re-reading https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom, I suspect the zip operator is your friend. It yields a tuple of arrays. Remains the challenge to convert that to an array of tuples. I'm a bit old-fashioned, so I'd use the good old `for` loop. My pseudo-code sketch of the solution looks like so:

```
const a$: Observable<Array<any>> = of([1, 2, 3]);
const b$: Observable<Array<any>> = of(['A', 'B', 'C']);
const result$ = zip(a$, b$).pipe(
  map(twoArrays => {
    const a = twoArrays[0];
    const b = twoArrays[1];
    const r: Array<[any, any]> = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      r.push([a[i], b[i]]);
    }
    return r;
  })
);
```

If you need a hashtable, you'd create an object instead of the array:

```
let r = {};
```

and define the key-value-pairs like so:

```
r[a[i]] = b[i];
```

**Update July 09, 2019:**
Just for the record, here's my first attempt, so you can understand the comments below complaining about the compiler errors.

```
const a$: Observable<Array<any>> = ...;
const b$: Observable<Array<any>> = ...;
const result$ = zip(a$, b$).pipe(
  map((a: Array<any>, b: Array<any>) => {
    let r: Array<[any, any]> = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      r.push([a[i], b[i]]);
    }
    return r;
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding me, when I don't know enough about this to accurately express myself.

Comment: Apparently you cant edit comments freely. Anyways, now I get the error "Argument of type '(a: any[], b: any[]) => [any, any][]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any[], index: number) => [any, any][]", and while I understand what its trying to tell me, I cant seem to find the mistake.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get from trying to write TypeScript without a compiler. :) The data structure are often slightly different than I'd expect. It takes a few months or years of experience to get familiar with this stuff. I've edited my answer, now it compiles.

Comment: Off-topic / meta: you can edit your comments after collection enough reputation on StackOverflow. Help other users, and you'll earn the priviledge quickly. That's the way StackOverflow protects itself from malicious bots.